# Creating a base class that implements a singleton for the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

So before you shoot me down telling me this is a terrible thing to do, I just want to state that I want to know this just for the sake of curiosity and possible code reduction. I want to have a base class that implements a singleton for a derived class. However, in doing so data is lost from the derived class. How can I get the base class to implement a singleton in terms of the derived class. Eg:

```
class Application{
public:
/**
 * @brief instance: C++11 [If control enters the declaration concurrently while the     variable is being initialized,
 *the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.—§6.7 [stmt.dcl] p4]
 * @return handle to application
 */
static Application& instance(){
    static Application s_Application;
    return s_Application;
}

void setName(std::string Name){
    AppName=Name;
}

std::string getName(){
    return AppName;
}
virtual ~Application(){ }

private:
Application(){}
std::string AppName;
};
```

Now I create a derived class that inherits from Application:

```
class Test:public Application{
    public:
    void printer(std::string test){
        std::cout<<"test\n";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Application test1=Test::instance();
    //Test test2=static_cast<Test>(test1);
    test1.setName("bla");
    test1.printer(test1.getName());
}
```

So as expected test1 cannot call the .printer() method since the returned object is of type 'Application'. Is there any way to pass the type of the derived class back to the main class and create an instance of the derived class?

**Edit: I have used CRTP to pass the value up, however when I do the following it doesn't equal each other:**

```
Test test1=Test::instance();
Test test2=Test::instance();
cout<<"Is test1 the same as test 2? "<<(&test1==&test2)<<endl;
```

The result of this is always **FALSE**.

Comment: Templated arguments come to mind.

Comment: CRTP... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried the CRTP route and this is a great idea. Only issue is that I would have to move the Constructor of Application to a protected member else I get this: "Untitled 4.cpp:9:24: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Test' static Derived s_Application;" . This seems like a bad idea for a singleton. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry was quick to respond here. I tried this, and then did the following:  Test test1=Test::instance();Test test2=Test::instance(); if(&test1==&test2){
  cout<<"test is eq";
 }else  {
  cout<<"test is not eq";
 } and it didn't equal :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to make copy constructor and assignment private so that one cannot copy the object (since only object has to exist).

In your code

```
Test test1=Test::instance();
Test test2=Test::instance();
```

You are actually calling

```
Test test1(Test::instance());
```

which is actually calling

```
Test (const Test &);
```

which is copy constructor and hence creating the copy of your object. And you are actually creating two different objects. That is why their address is different.

So, make copy constructor and assignment operator private so that no one can copy it.

And use the following

```
Test & test1 = Test::instance();
Test & test2 = Test::instance();
```

In this case, address will be same.

Or you can return pointer in `Test::instance` if you want.